# Is Guava drought-resistant

Tags: guavas

New planted guava plant soil is always wet due to close by raised bed water leak.
Will it survive with too much water. should i move my guava to different location.

Thank you !

Comment: what part of the world are you in, what type of soil (clay, sand, mix)? A photo would help too...

Comment: Why are you asking about drought resistance? Always-wet soil is the opposite of drought.